# My rails 3 engine's controller is only found by rails every second page refresh, otherwise returns LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

i'm developing a rails 3 engine but really having troubles getting the
controller to load every time.

every second time I visit the page I get;
    LoadError in Webedit/public filesController#index

```
Expected /home/anko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bundler/gems/webedit-3e02394235c3/app/controllers/public_files_controller.rb
to define PublicFilesController
```

to reproduce (assuming bash, ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3);

```
rails new webedit-test
cd webedit-test
echo "gem 'webedit', :git => 'https://github.com/ankopainting/webedit.git', :tag => 'v0.0.3'" >> Gemfile
bundle install
rails server
```

then goto http://localhost:3000/public

it will either say "hi" or an error.. refresh to see it change to the
opposite behaviour.

any help would be greatly appreciated.. I've spent some time in ruby
debugger but need to understand a lot about how rails works to get a
meaningful result.

Comment: Please show us what is in this `app/controllers/public_files_controller.rb`. What I'm looking for is the class definition at the top, so if you don't want to show the whole controller please at least show this.

Comment: https://github.com/ankopainting/webedit/blob/master/app/controllers/public_files_controller.rb  

I can't paste it but it's at the link above.

Answer (score 1):

I used the source code you provided and added a directory under controllers.  Seems to work fine now.  Since you have the controller inside a module, you need to create this directory structure:

```
app/controllers/webedit/public_files_controller.rb
```

Not exactly sure why it was loading every other time, though.